# BigCommerce api multiple stores in loop

Tags: php, api, foreach, bigcommerce

I'm currently creating a web app that needs to loop through multiple BigCommerce stores. Unfortunately, I can't get it to loop through when using the BigCommerce API.

I'm using the newest version of the BC API PHP library from GitHub (the one that uses namespacing), please see my code below:

```
require_once( 'autoload.php' );

use Bigcommerce\Api\Client as Bigcommerce;

$stores[1]['url'] = 'https://www.store1.co.uk';
$stores[1]['api_key'] = 'e01e16e6b51d70f6de213fd7445dc0f4';
$stores[1]['user'] = 'admin';
$stores[2]['url'] = 'https://www.store2.co.uk';
$stores[2]['api_key'] = '7b8b934e157eac734b7f7b4311b7cd81';
$stores[2]['user'] = 'admin';


foreach ( $stores as $store ){

    echo $store['url'] . ' - ';

    Bigcommerce::configure(array(
        'store_url' => $store['url'],
        'username'  => $store['user'],
        'api_key'   => $store['api_key'],
    ));

    Bigcommerce::setCipher('RC4-SHA');
    Bigcommerce::verifyPeer( false );

    $products = Bigcommerce::getProductsCount();

    echo $products . ' products<br />;

}
```

The expected output should be:

```
https://www.store1.co.uk - 301 products
https://www.store2.co.uk - 235 products
```

What I'm actually getting is:

```
https://www.store1.co.uk - 301 products
https://www.store2.co.uk -
```

I've worked with the API a few times before but have only ever connected to one store at a time/per project. Do I need to close the connection or something before I connect to the next store in the foreach loop?

All help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the following piece of code from Bigcommerce PHP library.

```
/**
     * Get an instance of the HTTP connection object. Initializes
     * the connection if it is not already active.
     *
     * @return Connection
     */
    private static function connection()
    {
        if (!self::$connection) {
            self::$connection = new Connection();
            self::$connection->authenticate(self::$username, self::$api_key);
        }

        return self::$connection;
    }
```

This is from Client.php - https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-php/blob/master/src/Bigcommerce/Api/Client.php

If you look at what you are doing, it will not work because, an existing connection will force the library to ignore new values. A new store connection is formed only when you are setting it for the first time.

An easy fix for your special use case would be to override the above function to reconnect to a new store irrespective of an existing connection.

Hope this works out!

Comment: Thanks Saran, sorry for the delay in responding. The project has been put on hold for the time being but I'm sure your advice will come in helpful for others and myself in the near future.